# Xcode test xib without compiling codes i.e Simulate the Xib/Window

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

I have used the Xcode feature of showing XIB without compiling the entire source code, this helps to get an idea of all the UI stuffs, of course few code/custom objects will not work here.

But in Xcode6, I am unable to find the option. I have used it a lot in Xcode3, 4 and 5.

In Xcode5 it is `Simulate Document` inside Editor: (In Xcode3.2 I used some keyboard shortcut, but with due course of time, it has been removed)

[image]

Could any one help me out for this, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this has been replaced in Xcode 6 with [Live Rendering](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Comment: @Droppy: I think Live Rendering is different thing. I updated my question, you might like to see.